# Active Directory Group Added to TFS Added as a User

Tags: security, active-directory, team-foundation-server

We have a TFS 2017 installation using Active Directory that has functioned fine for quite a while now (and continues to function fine except for one group in question).

We added a number of groups to Active Directory recently and provisioned them to a team project in TFS. All are fine except for one of them which is added as a user. Since it's added as a user, none of it's members get access to the team project.

I've verified that the group is entered in Active Directory as a Group (not as a User). I've cleared the client cache, the browser cache, and the server cache. I've also forced the Active Directory Sync to run (which completed successfully without errors), and attempted to add the Group from multiple clients. All workflows had the same result.

The TFS lookup can be seen here. Notice that it's recognized as a group in the lookup.

TFS Lookup Showing the Active Directory Group as a Group
[image: IMG:]

The group being added as a user from that lookup can be seen here. Notice that it's added as a user rather than a group. It also behaves like a user, not provisioning access to it's members.

[image: IMG:]

Does anyone know what's causing this or, at least, how I can add this group as a group so that it's members are successfully provisioned to the Team Project in question?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been a rare condition that will not often appear, but I'll answer so that the one other person who experiences this behavior 3 years from now will know what to do.

I wrote a small C# application to examine the properties of the group (including those that are hidden from most Active Directory GUI based tools) and discovered that the IsContainer property was set to false. I worked with the owners of the group to reset the value to true, and all functioned correctly thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same occurrence.

Groups created in the AD where recognized as users in the TFS Administration web site.
This happened multiple times on different test groups.

Finally, after an unknown event (logout, time elapsed ...) the groups created in the AD were propertly recognized as Groups. 
Note: our group names had a dash, the first group without a dash in the name worked...

I did not perform the analysis decribed by mattbbpl above (IsContainer Property).

If it is a bug in the AD administration app, this is quite the annoying issue...

Comment: I know this is quite old, but please, where can I see or change the IsContainer property?