# How can I change the IsContainer property of an AD Group?

Tags: active-directory, user-groups, attributes

This question is related to an answer of another question: https://superuser.com/a/1555013/298965

Please, how do I access, view or change the `IsContainer` property of an AD Group?

I have tried it in a Hyper-V Windows Server 2022. I have installed the `Active Directory Domain Services`. I have opened the `Active Directory Administrative Center` and created a new Group. However, when viewing the Group attributes, I cannot see any `isContainer` property:

[image: Attributes of my test group]

I have also tried editing the schema and "unhiding" the Container CN, based on this guide: https://www.robinhobo.com/how-to-create-container-objects-in-active-directory-not-ous/

However, no new attributes have been displayed.

Comment: The weird thing about that another question is that _groups actually aren't containers._ They don't "contain" any child entries the way OUs do; they only reference member entries through an attribute. Even if the IsContainer property were writable (which in itself doesn't make sense), I can't think of any reason why any tools would expect it to be set.

Comment: And on top of that, there is no IsContainer attribute _anywhere_ in the AD schema. So maybe that person wasn't talking about an LDAP attribute, but about some abstraction that C# provides – which might map to some entirely different LDAP attribute under the hood... I did find an [IsContainer property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.iscontainer?view=net-6.0) that certain C# objects have, but it is unclear what it actually corresponds to, and of course it is a read-only property.

Comment: I think what mattbbpl actually meant is that they somehow changed _something else_ in the group's entry which then resulted in the .NET "directory" API detecting it as a container... (Still can't see why a group would need that, though.)

Comment: @user1686 via extensive Googling and digging through the [.NET GitHub repo](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/System.Security.AccessControl/src/System/Security/AccessControl), I was able to find out that the IsContainer property is derived from this [COM interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadscontainer). But I still don't understand how is that connected to the AD attributes.